# Repository Pattern Multiple selectors

Tags: c#, linq, unit-of-work

Using a UnitOfWork Repository pattern I can access a reference using :

```
var tmp = unitOfWork.Repository<User>().Queryable();
```

I wish to query the table and recover an account where *AccountId* is an long:

```
result = a.Any(e => e.AccountId == AccountId);
```

This provides me with a record of the account for *AccountId*.

I also have a table called Emails which is linked to the Account table. So I now wish to update the query above to the following:

```
result = a.Any(e => 
    e.AccountId == AccountId &&
    e.Email.EmailID == EmailID
);
```

Where *EmailId* is a long. This should now pull an specific Email for a specific user account.

What I get is:

```
Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'User'
```

Comment: Can you rephrase the question a bit? I don't understand 1) what "look and see if a record exists Table1 and Table2 where the criteria match" means; 2) what does `a` in the second expression have to do with `tmp` in the first? Is `a` an `IQueryable<Table1>`? 3) `Table2` seems to be a collection inside `Table1`?

Comment: Can we see your entities (That was not a euphemism)?

Comment: i don't think you need to. Table user has primary key AccountId as a long, Table Email has a link to this field called AccountId and has a primary key called EmailID which is also a long. So the Iqueryable interface is comparing these fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that if I use the following it works for me.

```
Result = searchQuery.Any(e =>
                    e.AccountId == AccountId &&
                    e.Email.Any(f => f.Id == EmailId);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear exactly what you want, but

```
var tmp = unitOfWork.Repository<User>().Queryable();
```

should give you `IQueryable<User>` on which you can apply `Where` conditions, but you'll get result of `User` collection or object.

```
unitOfWork.Repository<User>().Queryable().Where(e => 
    e.AccountId == AccountId &&
    e.Email.EmailID == EmailID
);
```

If you want `Email` you should either load the `Email` with `User` object above or apply your condition on 
`unitOfWork.Repository<Email>().Queryable();`